# When printing unique extensions in the directory with the uniq command there are duplicates

Tags: command-line

```
for i in *; do echo ${i#*.}; done | uniq -u
```

Why there are duplicates in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Filter **adjacent** matching lines

...

> Note: 'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they  are  adjacent.
>          You  may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without 'uniq'.